# Can't get values from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am new to c# and have some questions about dictionaries. I can't get some values out of it.

This is my code for getting this dictionary over api.

```
public string GetDataDaily()
{
    var param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    param["symbol"] = "XBTUSD";
    param["binSize"] = "1d";

    param["count"] = "1";
    param["reverse"] = "true";

    return Query("GET", "/trade/bucketed", param);
}
```

This is the call for my method

```
var PivotLine = bitmex.GetDataDaily();            

txtPriceLastDay.Text = PivotLine["Open"];
```

This is the output from api request:

```
[{"timestamp":"2019-10 
  06T00:00:00.000Z","symbol":"XBTUSD","open":8188.5,"high":8207.5,"low":8035.5,"
  close":8170,"trades":41526,"volume":52477401,"vwap":8125.4571,"lastSize":2000, 
 "turnover":645864492821,"homeNotional":6458.644928209973,"foreignNotional":524 
     77401}]
```

I expected, that I can get open Price "8188.5, but I  can't run my code. The error is cant convert string to int.

Comment: You should try cast it to decimal/double since it's a decimal/double string, and before casting it, remove the last character (the comma) so it can be converted.

Comment: Your GetDataDaily doesn't return a dictionary, but a simple string, which happens to be json.

Answer (score 0):

GetDataDaily() returns a string but you want to get the Open price via index of an string.

the output is a JSON-string. you have to parse the string into an object (e.g. JSON.net).
after that, you can use dot-notation to get open price

Comment: okay I understand. I tried it this way: i created a class with get set properties for my json string. And this code:    HistoricPrices historicPrices = new HistoricPrices();
            HistoricPrices json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HistoricPrices>(PivotLine)
but got an error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'BitMexBot.HistoricPrices' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: sorry my answer was not completely correct. 
The API returns an array of json-object. The DeserializeObject Methods try to convert an array to your HistoricPrices object, which leads to your mistakes. 
try this: 
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HistoricPrices>>(PivotLine);
historicPrices = deserializedObject[0];
if it is possible, that the api returns multiple objects, than you have to iterate through the list (deserializedObject)

Comment: great, this is working. what you mean with that? if i have more than 1 day, do I need to set my deserializedObject[1] and get this price? Or with foreach?

Comment: foreach is better. if you use it, you dont change your code when you get 2-x days

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the last character (the comma) from the Price, then cast it to decimal.

```
example : 
decimal price = 0;
var isValid = decimal.TryParse(
      PivotLine["Open"].TrimEnd(',').Trim()                 // the source string, remove last comma, and trim whitespace if any.
    , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint   // to get the decimal point
    , new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true)   // CultureInfo
    , out price                                             // The parsed value if parsible. 
    );


if(isValid) 
{
    // if the conversion is Success
    txtPriceLastDay.Text = price.ToString(); // convert it to string again here. 
}
else    
{
    // IF conversion failed [Do Something]
    txtPriceLastDay.Text = "0.00";
}
```